# Android: java.lang.runtimeexception unable to instantiate activity componentinfo nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, timer, nullpointerexception, handler

I'm trying to get a timer to work, starting and stopping on button click events. I seem to be nullpointer referencing somewhere but i can't find the problem in my code. It would be really great if someone could help me out. This is the logcat error i keep getting. I have the activity added in my AndroidManifest.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{hva.ktv.getconnected/hva.ktv.getconnected.TestActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException

public class TestActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    a.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
    b.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private long mStartTime;
TextView mTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mStartTime == 0L) {
            mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
        }
    }

};

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final long start = mStartTime;
        long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        if (seconds < 10) {
            mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
        } else {
            mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        }

        mHandler.postAtTime(this, start
                + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
    }
};

OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Did u tried again with my update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following in onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    a.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
    b.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
}
```

There are two problems regarding to that piece of code, the first one is that you are setting a listener to Buttons a and b, and they're getting there null if you don't inflate them, by calling `findViewById(int res)`. But that's not actually your problem, take a look at this piece of code, which is executing before entering `onCreate(bundle)` method :

```
Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
TextView mTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Now, the problem is simple, you're trying to get those buttons and the TextView before calling setContentView(int layout), which will actually provide you those views for you. So, fixing the code will be easy, just replace your onCreate(bundle) method by this, (remember to delete the fields in which you inflate the widgets):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    TextView mTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    a.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
    b.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response however, after changing my code i still get the exact same error. Maybe it is for another reason this time?

Comment: Again thanks for your quick response. After applying these changes as well i get two errors in the mUpdateTimeTask method where i'm trying to set the text, 'mTimeLabel cannot be resolved'.

Comment: That's because you have to declare the buttons and the TextView as fields, but do not initialize them there, do it in onCreate method, where I told you to